# Hide frontpage content on homepage - Joomla 3.0 - Gantry

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a joomla site that I just want to have module content on the homepage. I have found other solutions but they seem to work on joomla 3.0 and the Gantry framework. Does anyone have an updated solution for this?

This is the code that I need to hide for the hompage:

```
    <?php /** Begin Main Body * */ ?>
        <?php echo $gantry->displayMainbody('mainbody', 'sidebar', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard'); ?>
    <?php /** End Main Body * */ ?>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to use a conditional to hide this code only for the hompage like in this post:

[Same idea for joomla 1.5 post](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=304129)

Comment: You should better use a dedicated template for your homepage

Comment: There isn't some sort of code to detect whether it is the frontpage and just use a conditional? like this post: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=304129

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the beginning of your template file right before the html part (but inside php tags):

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$isFrontPage = $menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault();
```

and then you can replace line with this:

```
<?php if (!$isFrontPage) echo $gantry->displayMainbody('mainbody', 'sidebar', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add a new position called disable_content and check if there are active modules in there.
If so you don't display the content.

To add a position edit you templateDetails.xml in `<positions>`

```xml
<positions>
    ..
    <position>disable_content</position>
```

Now to check if you have active modules in there simply use :

```php
$disable_content = (bool) $this->countModules('disable_content');
```

So now you can use

```php
<?php if (!$disable_content) : ?>
    <?php echo $gantry->displayMainbody('mainbody', 'sidebar', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard', 'standard'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```